# How to limit loops when using foreach

Tags: php

I have a code like this to check whether in the cart there are product IDs == 13,

```
foreach ($_cart as $key => $value1){
if( in_array( 13 ,$value1 ) ){ 
.....some code.....
}
else {
...some code ....
}
```

What I want is that if there is a product with id 13 then the foreach only does a loop twice and if it is not there then only do it once. How to?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to break the loop if there are two products with the ID of 13?
In that case, you can make use of an incremental counter:

```
$product_13_count = 0;

foreach ($_cart as $key => $value1) {
    if (in_array(13, $value1)) { 
      $product_13_count++; // Increase count based on the number of instances of product 13
      if ($product_13_count > 2) {
        break; // Too much of product 13
      }
      else {
        // Continue -- there are acceptable levels of product 13
      }
    }
    else {
      // Not product 13
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using counting the iterations:

```php
<?php
$iterations = 1;
foreach ($_cart as $key => $value1){
  if ($iterations > 2) {
    break;
  }
  if( in_array( 13 ,$value1 ) ){ 
    .....some code.....
  }
  else {
    ...some code ....
  }
  $iterations++;
```